# Define global custom post

Tags: php, wp-query, globals

I have create a custom post object with custom post metas.

Like this:

```
$post->custom_meta = get_post_meta();

$custom_post = $post;
```

Am I how to define the `$custom_post` object to global in master level?

Can I request any file it like `single.php`

```php
global $custom_post;

the_title();

echo $custom_post->custom_meta;
```

or `index.php`

```php
global $custom_post;

// The Loop
if ( $custom_post->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $custom_post->have_posts() ) {
        $custom_post->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        echo $custom_post->custom_meta;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

How to set `$custom_post` an global and in where? (`functions.php`?) thx.

Comment: Why would you want to do that when you could simply call `get_post_meta()` in your loop (and basically, everwhere in WordPress - templates, template parts, etc).

Comment: `global` is not good practice in PHP anymore. Have you looked into other more recent programming patterns to solve this?